# Synchronization between processes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, thread-safety, windows-phone

I'm working with Windows Phone 8 and I'm curious if I can make my UI Thread wait until background process finishes its job or send a special signal.
I've tried to do this with Mutex Class but the biggest problem is that I cannot exacly be sure that backgroud process invokes WaitOne() before UI thread does - if WaitOne() from UI thread is faster then I can dream about my synchronization.
Does anyone know the solution or can show me the path where can I learn someting about that?

Comment: Well, wrong synchronization object, you'd use an event instead.  EventWaitHandle class in .NET.  A background process on a phone???

Comment: Yes - for example Background Audio Agent. I will have to read about this events - do you know any good examples? Especially I would like to know how two processes can invoke to the same event - how to declare that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Hans Passant suggestion I've made some further research concerning EventWaitHandle, and I've found a [nice page](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles).
I've created in one process:

```
EventWaitHandle eW = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "Romasz.Event");
eW.WaitOne();
```

And in second:

```
EventWaitHandle eW;
bool yes = EventWaitHandle.TryOpenExisting("Romasz.Event", out eW);
if (yes) eW.Set();
```

Works great - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily manage this with another approach using INotifyPropertyChanged and Progressbar

like at the completion of process kindly change the value of bool to true and at value changed of progressbar you can easily do whatever n that event, it can easily implement in MVVM too

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are thinking of. Can you expand a little your answer?

Comment: @Romasz have you know the Inotifypropertychanged? I can post it code if you want

Comment: I asked about two different processes that doesn't share resources (like two different Apps). Can you do it with INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Romasz yea if you can tell me the process description

Comment: For example - I've background agent which is responsible for downloading a file and save it to IsolatedStorage, I want it to notify my main UI process when it finishes - how do you want to do it with INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Romasz ok for that I can do  that

Comment: you told about two processes?

Comment: @Romasz are you using MVVM

Comment: Yes I mean two processes not threads nor methods, I think the pattern I follow has nothing to do with that. Sorry, but it starts to look like a chat which is not suitable for this site - if you have a peace of code or link with example please post it.

Comment: @Romasz you can declare the boolean which is binded with progressbar. when your processes completes, it will change the bool to false. so progressbar's value changes event will occur so in that event you can post your code